# UnsafePointer in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, unsafe-pointers

I know this question was asked several times but I really don't understand it.

I want to extract a value from a bluetooth device (miband).
In swift 2 it worked like this:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "FF06" {
        let value = UnsafePointer<Int>(characteristic.value!.bytes).memory
        print("Steps: \(value)")
    }
}
```

But in swift 3 it throws an error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<Int>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeRawPointer)'
```

And I have no idea how to migrate that to swift 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `withUnsafeBytes` with `pointee`:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "FF06" {
        let value = characteristic.value!.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) -> Int in
            return pointer.pointee
        }
        print("Steps: \(value)")
    }
}
```

If the `UnsafePointer` was pointing to an array of `Pointee`, then you could use the subscript operator, e.g. `pointer[0]`, `pointer[1]`, etc., rather than `pointer.pointee`.

For more information, see [SE-0107](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/545e7bea606f87a7ff4decf656954b0219e037d3/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md).

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.